# Expo Facebook login not returning an expires value, am I missing something?

Tags: react-native, mobile, cross-platform, expo, facebook-authentication

I am using the Expo framework, and working on implementing Facebook login.

The [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook#expofacebookloginwithreadpermissionsasync) suggests I should get three values back, **type**, **token** and **expires**. **Type** and **token** are coming back as they should, but expires is not. Am I missing something?

Relevant code is below:

```
async logIn() {
  const { type, token, expires } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('my-app-id', {
      permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
  if (type === 'success') {

    Alert.alert(type);
    Alert.alert(token);

    if(expires) {
      Alert.alert(expires);
    }
    else {
      Alert.alert('nope');
    }
```

Basically trying to work out if I've missed something, or if the documentation is out of date. I am using the latest version of Expo (30.0.1).

Thanks

Comment: Works for me with 30.0.0

Comment: @Yossi, Thanks, interesting, are you on Windows or macOS, also targeting Android or iOS?

Comment: Windows, testing on an android emulator.

Comment: @Yossi Thanks, maybe I'm doing something stupid 

Comment: My code is identical. What is 30.0.1? I am using 30.0.0...

Comment: My package.json shows *expo:30.0.1*

Comment: Right, mine too... I was looking at the following line: "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181820/discussion-between-jmk-and-yossi).